# Pollard rho integer factorization

Tags: java, c++, c, math, factorization

I am trying to implement Pollard Rho integer factorization in C/C++.Google gives me a Java implementation of the problem [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/78crypto/PollardRho.java.html).

I don't know Java that well,so what I came up with [this](http://ideone.com/MVrvmTCN).My implemenation in C++ works for most cases but not in few like the one "9999", I used there.

I am aware that C++ didn't have Biginteger class so I can't have the full functionality as it gives in JAVA but I want to factorize 15 digits numbers that's sufficient for `unsigned long long`

Please point out what wrong in my implementation.

Comment: Any chance you could paste your C code in the question, so that it's available for posterity?  (Or is that not appropriate?  I'm a relative newcomer to SO; perhaps 60-line pastes are frowned upon.)

Comment: There are big integer implementations for C++ too. The most popular one is probably the one by GNU: http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem's right here:

```
#define abs(x) (x>0)?(x):(-x)
```

You're missing some parentheses in your `abs` macro.  Try:

```
#define abs(x) ((x)>0 ? (x) : -(x))
```

instead.  (Consider what happens when `abs(x-xx)` is expanded in the case `x-xx <= 0`.)

Also, why does your gcd function return an int rather than a BigInteger?

You should also be aware that (assuming unsigned long long is a 64-bit integer type) this code won't work correctly for `N` larger than `2**32`:  if `x` (or `xx`) is greater than or equal to `2**32` then `x*x` will wrap modulo `2**64`, giving you the wrong value for `x*x % N`.

Comment: This is why inline functions are preferable to macros wherever possible.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not the missing parentheses but the *misplaced* parenthesis next to the minus sign that really matters. For safely performing the multiplication, look-up SqrMod and MultiplyMod.

Answer (score 2):

I've spotted one difference: the Java code assigns `c` and `x` to be `new BigInteger(N.bitLength(), random)`, whereas the C++ code uses `rand() % N`, which is a smaller random range. For the value 9999, the binary is 10011100001111, so the Java code will give `c` and `x` a maximum value of 16383.

Comment: The smaller range of rand() might affect the performance when N is larger than 32767, but your explanation about what happens when N=9999 didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I made an off by one typo: 9999 decimal is 10011100001111, and takes 14 bits to represent. If N=9999, `BigInteger(N.bitLength(), random)` will produce an integer from 0 to 2^14-1, whereas `rand() % N` will produce an integer from 0 to 9998. It's not the key bug in the code, but it's also not an accurate translation of the Java version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ~100 lines C implementation of Pollard Rho :

There is some **helpers** :

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint_fast64_t num ;

static inline num mul_mod(num a, num b, const num mod) {
    // Return (a * b) % mod, avoiding overflow errors while doing modular multiplication.
    num res = 0, tmp;
    for (b %= mod; a; a & 1 ? b >= mod - res ? res -= mod : 0, res += b : 0, a >>= 1, (tmp = b) >= mod - b ? tmp -= mod : 0, b += tmp);
    return res % mod;
}

static inline num square_root(num n) {
    // Return the number that was multiplied by itself to reach N.
    num a = 0, b, c;
    for (b = 1ULL << 62; b; c = a + b, n -= c &= -(n >= c), a = (a >> 1) | (c & b), b >>= 2);
    // Variable n contains the remainder.
    return a;
}
```

There is a required **prime checker** :

```c
static  int is_prime(const num n, size_t iterations) {
    // Perform a Miller-Rabin (strong probable prime) test.
    num a = 0, b, c, d, e, f; int h, i;
    if ((n == 1) == (n & 1)) return n == 2;
    for (b = c = n - 1, h = 0; !(b & 1); b >>= 1, ++h);
    for (; iterations--;) {
        for (size_t g = 0; g < sizeof(a); ((char*)&a)[g++] = rand()); // random input.
        do for (d = e = 1 + a % c, f = n; (d %= f) && (f %= d););
        while (d > 1 && f > 1);
        for (d = f = 1; f <= b; f <<= 1);
        for (; f >>= 1; d = mul_mod(d, d, n), f & b && (d = mul_mod(e, d, n)));
        if (d == 1) continue;
        for (i = h; i-- && d != c; d = mul_mod(d, d, n));
        if (d != c) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

There is two factorization functions :

```c
static inline num factor_worker_2(const num n, size_t limit) {
    // Perform a Pollard's Rho probabilistic test.
    size_t a = -1, b = 2;
    num c, d = 1 + rand(), e = 1, f = 1;
    for (c = d %= n; f == 1 && --limit; d = c, b <<= 1, a = -1) {
        for (; f |= e, f == 1 && ++a != b;) {
            c = mul_mod(c, c, n);
            for (++c, c *= c != n, e = n, f = c > d ? c - d : d - c; (f %= e) && (e %= f););
        }
    }
    return f;
}

static inline num factor_worker_1(const num n) {
    // Perform a trial divisions test on N.
    static const num list[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 1};
    size_t i;
    for (i = -1; n % list[++i];);
    return list[i];
}
```

There is a factorizarion **manager** :

```c
num factor(const num n) {
// Basic factorization manager, detect primes, perfect squares, execute workers.
    num res;
    switch (n) {
        case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
            res = 1; break;
        default:
            res = factor_worker_1(n);
            if (res == 1 && !is_prime(n, 20)) {
                res = square_root(n);
                if (res * res != n)
                    for(;res = factor_worker_2(n, -1), res == 1 || res == n;);
            }
    }
    return res;
}
```

There is a **main** :

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    num N;
    N = 951818131364430049;
    printf("factor is %zu\n", factor(N));
}
```

To **try it** :

```
// You can put it into a main.c file then compile + execute :
// gcc -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic main.c ; ./a.out ;
```

Here is the [source](https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-RHO) for more informations, Thank You.